# How to check element is child of specific element?

Tags: javascript, html

If I get `elementA` and `elementB` with `document.querySelector`, how to can I check if `elementA` is a child element of `elementB` without `jQuery`?

Considering `elementA` maybe not first level child of `elementB`.

Exemple: http://jsbin.com/jijoqicozo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you show enough HTML, and your attempted JavaScript, so that we can reproduce what you've attempted?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains / FYI: Children are always "first level". Nodes further down the tree are called descendants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use B.contains(A) to determine if element A is a descendent of element B.

Note that node.contains is inclusive, meaning that B.contains(B) === true

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Comment: Maybe this is a solution for my question!!